# FILTER or QUERY multiple ranges with blanks removed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to query or filter multiple ranges but am running into a situation with blank cells as I need all the ranges merged without blanks inbetween.
Here is the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qaJHg_vWpgIvj0fwHmyGMi8Iv-jpjExVstPoxXWsfUA/edit#gid=0) which has both my query and filter attempts.

Sample source data:

[image: WA110862 question example]

```
    A       B    C     D    E 
1
2   RANGE 1 JIM  JON  STAN  BOB
3   RANGE 2 JOE  LUKE MEL   
4   RANGE 3      DAVE DON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QUERY` has a inbuilt option to remove blanks:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({B2:E2,B3:E3,B4:E4}),"select * where Col1 is not null"))
```

This is a alternative solution, which does not require you to list all the ranges (useful, if there are 1000s of  ranges)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRIM(CONCATENATE(QUERY(B2:E4&" ",, 50000)))," ", 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=split(textjoin("|",1,QUERY({B2:E2,B3:E3,B4:E4},"select *")),"|")
```

[TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) has the option to exclude blank cells when concatenating them and the string can then be separated with [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136).